# Class - return data via await?

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

I am learning how to use `class` with Async/Await. I think I am doing something wrong with `getData` function in the `Run` class.

It should output "Hello World" when using `await get()` (experiment).

When I run the script, I get an error:

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This
>   error originated either by throwing inside of an async function
>   without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled
>   with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)

Class Script:

```
class Run {
    constructor() {
        this.stop = false;
    }

    async getData(entry) {
        if (this.stop) {
            console.log("Stopped")
            return;
        }

        return await this.get();
    }

    async get() {
        return "Hello World";
    }

    stop() {
        this.stop = true;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
let run =  new Run();

run.getData(async (entry) => { 
    console.log(entry);
});
```

Comment: You never use `entry` anywhere?

Comment: You cannot have a method and a data property both named `stop`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting an error because you forgot the `this` qualifier:

```
async getData(entry) {
    if (this.stop) {
        ^^^^
```

---

Using `return await` only makes sense, when you use it within a try/catch block. Otherwise, it is completely redundant.

You should use it here instead. Also, `getData` does not use its parameter `entry`. You should call it directly:

```
console.log(await run.getData());
            ^^^^^
```

Answer (score 0):

Your original code refer to the other methods, not the one in your class:

```
async getData(entry) {
    if (stop) {  // <--- this refers to this.stop() method
        console.log("Stopped")
        return;
    }

    return await get(); <--- this doesn't refer to your `this.get()` method
}
```

So, add `this.` to fix it at above two positions.